# hide e-mail on mailto: (conversion from javascript to c#/ASP.NET MVC)

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to make the email that appears on the mailto: on a, for example:
     mail-me
I've got a code in javascript doing this in a little different way:

```js
function validacaoEmail(field) {
  user = field.value.substring(0, field.value.indexOf("@"));
  domain = field.value.substring(field.value.indexOf("@")+ 1, field.value.length);
  if ((user.length >=1) && (domain.length >=3) && (user.search("@")==-1) && (domain.search("@")==-1) && (user.search(" ")==-1) && (domain.search(" ")==-1) && (domain.search(".")!=-1) && (domain.indexOf(".") >=1)&& (domain.lastIndexOf(".") < domain.length - 1)) {
   domainend = "@"+domain;
   toonclick = 'this.href="'+'mailto:'+user+domainend+'"'; 

   document.getElementById("msgemail").innerHTML="<a href='"+user+'@'+domain+"' rel='nofollow' onclick='" +toonclick+ "'>" +user+ "<span style='display:none'>null</span>" +domainend+ "</a>";
  }
 }
```

```html
<form name="f1">
<h3>Formulário de Inscrição:</h3>
<table>
<tr>
<td>
<b>Don't click enter, click outside of the box after insert the e-mail</b>
E-mail:
<input type="text" name="email" onblur="validacaoEmail(f1.email)"  maxlength="60" size='65'>
</td>
<td>
<div id="msgemail"></div>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>
```

Comment: What do you want the code to do? What is it doing now that doesn't meet your expectations?

Comment: Hi, i also don't understand from what you've said what your question is or whats wrong

Comment: i want to make what this code is doing but in a controller on mvc

Comment: try the html code and you will understand what is he doing, then i want to pass it to my controller in asp.net mvc

Comment: Are you really sure, that applying client-side logic on the server-side is a good idea?

Comment: @LETLSkyfall do you mean, you would like to know how to do server side model validation ?

Comment: yes i would like to make it work in the best way on the controller doing what the javascript is doing but i don't know how

Comment: Whats your controller look like at the moment? can u post that as well please :)

So what im getting is on submitting that form you want to validate the email server side as well?

Comment: where do you want to see the controller? my controller don't actually have a textbox, it is something that just receive the email from a variable and then verify if it is an email and transform him, but now i want to do it with an mailto: too

Comment: anyway there is a link to pastebin with the controller: https://pastebin.com/4xW5uePp

Answer (score 0):

include a new reference to System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations
you have the choice of a regex or something like this : http://dataannotationsextensions.org/

Create Model server side:

```
public class MyFormViewModel{
[Required]
[DataType(DataType.EmailAddress)]
[EmailAddress] or [RegularExpression(*expression here*)]

Public String Email {Get;Set;}
}
```

Create controller action:

```
[Post]
public ActionResult Submit(MyFormViewModel viewModel){
if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
//Do what ever
            return View("Completed");
        }
        else
        {            
//error do something
             return View();
        }
}
```

If your using razor you can validate client side as well using your models and messages on them using :

```
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Email)
```

and in your model:

```
[Required(ErrorMessage = "Email is required")]
```

hope that helps not sure

Comment: I don't think I've understood maybe why you'd want to do mail to in the controller, unless you mean sending emails via the server?

Comment: Actually it just verify if it have an e-mail, now i need to transform the e-mail that it got to imagine the situation: < a href = " mailto: 123@test.com " >mail me< /a > and i need this: < a href = " mailto: " + user + domainend + "" > mail me < /a > i'm sorry if i'm not expressing me too nice but my english is not the best